# Java UTF-8 URLEncoder encoding special characters that it shouldn't

Tags: java, android

I am trying to encode the username and password when logging in my mobile app. I am connecting to an existing API and am supposed to send an encoded username and password. I am using URLEncoder using UTF_8 but it seems to be encoding most special characters. I am comparing the encoded string to the one encoded by Postman (which is the correct version).

Here is my code:

```
URLEncoder.encode(value, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
```

For the string ~!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:<>?"`[]\;',./

In postman it is being encoded as

```
~!%40%23%24%25%5E%26*()_%2B%7B%7D%7C%3A%3C%3E%3F%22%60%5B%5D%5C%3B'%2C.%2F
```

while in my app, it is being encoded as

```
%7E%21%40%23%24%25%5E%26*%28%29_%2B%7B%7D%7C%3A%3C%3E%3F%22%60%5B%5D%5C%3B%27%2C.%2F
```

As you can see, it is encoding most special characters (The exceptions being ._*)

Answer (score 4):

Using the static constant `UTF_8`'s `toString()` method as the character encoding scheme throws `java.nio.charset.IllegalCharsetNameException: java.nio.charset.CharsetICU[UTF-8]` as the `toString()` returns "java.nio.charset.CharsetICU[UTF-8]". To get the desired "UTF-8" use `displayName()` method instead.

After that change your code work's like you wanted in my environment.

Comment: Hi. My code is not throwing an exception like that. I just tried the displayName() method and it the result is still the same